# pandas:how to change all column names with erasing specific letters

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Anaconda to read table from hive and all my column names have been automaticly added a prefix like test.age,test.sex,test.degree...
How to use pandas to erase all the prefix 'test.'?

Comment: You don't show any evidence of what you've tried in order to address this problem, which is the reason I haven't provided an answer. I suggest you look at the `pandas.DataFrame.columns` attribute

Comment: kindly provide what you have tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

one way to do it is:

```
df.columns = [i.replace("test.", "") for i in df.columns]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df.columns = [i[1] for i in df.columns.str.split('.')]
```